# Metrization of the Chabauty topology

Tags: integration, general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I am trying to read this paper, [Metrizing the Chabauty topology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.07396), but it is quite brief and it doesn't clarify enough its construction so I was hoping someone could help explain the construction it gives.

The paper deals with metrizing the Chabauty topology on the space of closed subsets of a proper metric space $M$. It says that an appropriate metric for this topology is

$$ d:\mathcal{C}(M)\times \mathcal{C}(M)\to [0,\infty), \quad d(A,B)= \int_0^\infty e^{-R}d_R(A,B)\cdot dR, $$

but I am unclear as to what this integral is exactly supposed to mean. It defines for $A\in \mathcal{C}(M)$ and $R>0$

$$ A_R:=A\cap \overline{  B(p,r) }, $$

and then defines for each $R>0$ a bounded pseudo-metric on $\mathcal{C}(M)$ by

$$  d_R(A,B):= \min \{ 1,d_{\text{Haus}}(A_R,B_R) \}. $$

Now I am familiar with defining integrals via simple functions or Stieltjes integral, but I am not sure what to make of this notation. Secnod, earlier in the paper he fixes a base point $p\in M$, and then does not refer to it later. Then the metric should be dependent on $p$, unless explained otherwise.

I have not yet dealt with the important details of the proof, since I could not properly grasp the definition which I think is at the base of it, so would appreciate remarks that would help clarify the definition.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand is to look how it work on an example.
For example

Let $M= \mathbb{R},$ $p=0$,$A=[0,1]$, $B=[0,2]$ $A_R =[0,R] $ for $0<R\leq 1 $ and $A_R =[0,1] $ for $R>1 $, $B_R =[0,R] $ for $0<R\leq 2 $ and $B_R =[0,1] $ for $R>2. $

$$d_{HAUSS} (A_R , B_R ) =\begin{cases} 0 \mbox{ for } 0<R\leq 1 \\ R-1 \mbox{ for } 1<R<\leq 2 \\ 1 \mbox{ for } R>2 \end{cases} $$ thus $$d_R (A, B) = d_{HAUSS} (A_R , B_R )$$
and we get $$d(A, B) =\int_1^2 (R-1)e^{-R} dR + \int_2^{\infty} e^{-R} dR $$